# Custom colors for group of bars in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to have custom colors for a group of bars in Matlab bar plot.

[image: For example this]

Like the one showed here but with different colors. How can I do this?

I tried to use the following code but it shows stacked bars instead of the groups.

```
xdata = [1 2 3];
ydata = [10 20 30; 40 50 60; 5 6 7];
clr = [0 0.8 0;
   0.3 0.8 0.8;
   0 0 1];

for i = 1:length(xdata)
    p = bar(xdata, ydata(i,:));
    hold on
    set(p,'FaceColor', clr(i,:));
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by assigning a handle to your bar plot, and then change the `FaceColor` property afterward. The handles will actually be an array of handles, each containing the properties of every individual patch object making up the bar plot. That's then easy to change any property you want:

```
clear
clc

close all

xdata = [1 2 3];
ydata = [10 20 30; 40 50 60; 5 6 7];
clr = [0 0.8 0;
   0.3 0.8 0.8;
   0 0 1];

hBar = bar(ydata);

for k = 1:numel(hBar)
set(hBar(k),'FaceColor',clr(:,k))

end
```

Output:

[image]

hBar is a 3x1 structure containing the properties of each individual patch objects forming the plot:

The handles:

```
hBar =

  175.0597  178.0494  180.0494
```

And if you type `get(hBar)` you get :

```
3x1 struct array with fields:

    Annotation
    DisplayName
    HitTestArea
    BeingDeleted
    ButtonDownFcn
    Children
    ...
    And so on
    ...
```